# How and where to find a good community manager?

Tags: moderators, site-administration, community-organizing, volunteers, leadership

- What are the **criteria** for being a good community manager?
- What **expectations** can you have from a good community manager?
- Where is the **best place** to look for someone to manage a starting
  community?
- Do you look **internally or externally** when posting a job opening?
- What level of **affinity** does a community manager need to have with
  the community's topic?
- Is a community manager preferably an **active member**, or merely an
  overseeing **moderator** of a community?
- What is the preferred **compensation** for a good community manager
  (ranging from volunteer to ...)?

Comment: That's likely too many questions to ask in a single post to elicit a good response.  Perhaps narrow the focus?

Comment: As @RockPaperLz-MaskitorCasket said, questions on SE tend to work best when you ask one question per post (or a closely related set of questions, such that an answer to one Q would naturally answer the others in the same post). As such, I'd suggest splitting this into a few posts: (1) What makes someone a good CM? (2) Where/how should I look for a CM? (3) What level of affinity does a CM need to have with the community's topic? (4) How engaged/active should a CM be in terms of participation in the community? [This could be part of #1 as well.] (5) What is the preferred compensation for a CM?

Comment: That said, I'm not sure if all of those questions (especially the last one) are the best fit for the Stack Exchange format, so make sure to read the [help] if you haven't already done so, especially the pages on [what's on-topic for the site](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) and [what types of questions to avoid asking](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask). Feel free to ask on [meta] if you have other questions about how the site works that aren't already answered there. Welcome to the [communitybuilding.se] site!